A Fantasy story where a man appears to have been crushed on his wedding night by a statue on the finger of which he has put a wedding ring
I read this Fantasy short story in high school, in the late 60's. I read it in French in a collection. It was not a collection of Fantasy, this story just one Fantasy story among several mainstream stories by the same French author, probably of the 19th century. I just checked, not Théophile Gautier, who wrote la Cafetière.
Fantasy short story where an artist sees in an oneiric vision a woman who has died years earlier
Aa antique (Greek or Roman) statue has been found. Unearthed or maybe found in the wreck of some sunk ship, I am not sure. It is very heavy, so it is just left exposed outside.
On the morning of his wedding day, a man is wearing on his finger the wedding ring he means to give to his bride a few hours later. But before that he decides to play a ball game where one uses the hand. He feels that the ring hinders him. The game is played near the place the statue is exposed, so he takes the ring off his finger and puts it on one of the statue's fingers. But at the end of the game he is unable to take it off the statue.
At the wedding he has to use some other ring as wedding ring. He tells a friend that he thinks the statue has closed her finger on the ring and asks his friend to go check it. But the friend thinks it is a joke and does not check.
After the wedding the newlywed keeps drinking with his buddies and joins his wife very late, when she was already asleep. The next morning his wife finds him dead, his body apparently crushed under a heavy weight.
The general feeling is that the statue has come at night to take her "betrothed" because of the wedding ring.

La Vénus d'Ille by Prosper Mérimée.
La Vénus d'Ille is a short story by French writer Prosper Mérimée. It was written in 1835 and published in 1837. It tells the story of a statue of Venus that comes to life and kills the son of its owner, whom it believes to be its husband. This is based on a popular medieval story, of which William of Malmesbury wrote the earliest known version.
The plot summary that Wikipedia gives is:

Before the wedding, the groom decides to play a game of Paume, and he slips the wedding ring intended for his fiancée onto a finger of the statue. He wins the game, but his opponent swears revenge. He accidentally leaves the ring with the statue; and when he goes back later to retrieve it, he discovers that the statue has closed her fingers around it. The narrator does not believe Alphonse's story, since Alphonse has been drinking heavily at the reception, and he goes to bed.
During the night, the narrator hears heavy footsteps climbing the stairs; but he assumes that it is a drunken Alphonse going to bed. In the morning, after the cock's crow, he hears the same steps retreating down the stairs. Suddenly, there is screaming and commotion. The narrator runs down the hall to find a crowd of people surrounding the dead Alphonse, who looks as though he died in a fiery embrace.


Yes, exactly right.

Tim Powers' The Stress Of Her Regard starts this way too (I was expecting it to be the accepted answer), except it's the main character's new bride that gets messily killed the night after he leaves his wedding ring on a statue's finger. I wonder if he was inspired by this story.

@Shawn "The Stress Of Her Regard" is a novel published in 1989, not a short story published long before 1970, so it could hardly be the accepted answer. But whether "La Vénus d'Ille" was his inspiration is quite possible.
